# how do i parse this

Tags: ruby, json

I am trying to parse json below like this and i get an error saying key is a string not a hash. I am trying to extract data for position, name, id, team and push it into a ruby hash by position type.

```
require 'json'
json = JSON.parse(response.body)
json.each do |key, value|
    if(key =~ /players/)        
         key.each do |k, v|
           puts k.inspect
         end
    end
 end




{
      "version": "1.0",
      "players": {
        "timestamp": "-1",
        "player": [
          {
            "position": "TMDL",
            "name": "Bills, Buffalo",
            "id": "0251",
            "team": "BUF"
          },
          {
            "position": "TMDL",
            "name": "Colts, Indianapolis",
            "id": "0252",
            "team": "IND"
          },
          {
            "position": "TMDL",
            "name": "Dolphins, Miami",
            "id": "0253",
            "team": "MIA"
          }
         ]
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `players` is a unique key, you can access it directly with `json["players"]`. I think you're looking for something like this:

```
require 'json'
json = JSON.parse(response.body)
json["players"]["player"].each do |player|
   puts "Player team is #{player['name']} and position is #{player['position']}"
end
```

Comment: that did it. :) never occured to me i could use it as a ruby hash after calling json.parse. still new to ruby.

Answer (score 1):

the json variable is already a hash (after parse), you can use it like a normal ruby hash.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this one:

```
require 'json'
require 'ostruct'
require 'awesome_print'

test = '{
    "version": "1.0",
    "players": {
      "timestamp": "-1",
      "player": [
        {
          "position": "TMDL",
          "name": "Bills, Buffalo",
          "id": "0251",
          "team": "BUF"
        },
        {
          "position": "TMDL",
          "name": "Colts, Indianapolis",
          "id": "0252",
          "team": "IND"
        },
        {
          "position": "TMDL",
          "name": "Dolphins, Miami",
          "id": "0253",
          "team": "MIA"
        }
       ]
    }
}'



json = JSON.parse(test)
json.each do |key, value|
  if(key =~ /players/)
       value['player'].each do |k, v|
         puts k.inspect
       end
  end
end
```